# Using a script to organize music library

Tags: file, rename, file-rename

Not sure if this is the correct section or whether I should try SuperUser, but here goes.

I have a ton of music (around 70GB) in my library that I would like to organize, rename, etc. Is it possible to do this using some kind of script? I am not familiar with this type of thing at all, just to put things in perspective.

I have the metadata organized (artist name, album name, track no, track name, etc.) already so if I could write a script to organize my folders and files that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that: of course it's possible. You simply need to use a tool that helps you read existing tags in music files. This might depend on the format of the music files, and of course which operating system you are using.

Following on from that, all OSes have the ability to move files, so it's a case of running the metadata query on the file then using the outputs to rename.

For MP3s you can use, for example, `id3` on Linux.

You might also want to look at beets - http://beets.radbox.org/